# How do I get the highest sum by adding values from two alternate columns?

Tags: r

I have the following Time Series, the Row Nr column only for clarity here.

```
    TIME            A      B     Row Nr

    09:00:00.009   -2      1     1
    09:00:00.009    0     -1     2
    09:00:03.051    1     -2     3
    09:00:03.053   -1      1     4
    09:00:03.220   -3      2     5
    09:00:03.222   -5      2     6
    09:00:03.224    3     -4     7
    09:00:03.225    2     -3     8
    09:00:03.228   -1      0     9
```

**Example**
For a test with the minimum values for changing columns A=0 and B=1, and we start on column A, it would go like this:

Row nr:

1. A = -2 is less than 0, so do nothing. Sum = 0
2. A = 0, so move to column B and add 0 to Sum.
3. B = -2, less than 1, so do nothing.
4. B = 1, move to a and add 1 to sum, Sum = 1
5. A = -3, less than 0. Do nothing.
6. A = -5, do nothing.
7. A = 3, move to B. Sum = 1 + 3 = 4
8. B = -3, do nothing.
9. B = 0, do nothing.

Sum is 4 after being run with minimum parameters A=0 and B=1. How do I find the parameters for minimum A and B that will result in the biggest Sum?

I keep the old explanation of the problem below. This will be done on large datasets lots of times.

---

I need to be on either column A, B while going through the time serie. I can at any time move from column A to B, and then adds the value on that row in column A to a sum, and then I may go from column B to A at any row after that and add the B value to my sum.

I can move as many time as I want between the columns, and I wan't to end up with the greatest sum.

What I'm now looking for is two minimum values, one that is the least value to make me move from A to B, and the other one to move from B to A.

What I'm looking for is if there is some packages that deals with this kind of problem, or maybe some hints in the direction towards a better solution than brute forcing. I will do this alot, so performance is a factor._

Comment: Perhaps `pmax` will be useful

Comment: @docendodiscimus I was thinking along the same lines, but after reconsideration I believe that the OP is looking for a solution that involves the smallest number of changes from column A to column B. I think that such a constraint is not trivial to implement.

Comment: If they want the maximum sum, then I don't see how moves from A to B could be minimized except by ordering the data beforehand. But I may not understand the question fully.

Comment: @docendodiscimus I agree; if there is such a constraint as I suspect, the penalization for a change should somehow be quantified. I might have misunderstood the question.

Comment: can you provide the desired output for the example in your question? it's not very clear what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the sum of the row-wise maxima then it's:

```
with( dfrmname , sum( pmax(A ,B) ) # should be quite fast.
```

If you want to construct a cumulative sum, then it's:

```
with( dfrmname , cumsum( pmax(A ,B) )
```